# Drive function in MicroPython for LEGO EV3

Tags: python, robotics, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3, pybricks-micropython

I'm trying to understand the functions from DriveBase class from MicroPython for EV3.
I instantiate the DriveBase object like this

```
robot = DriveBase(left_motor, right_motor, wheel_diameter=55.5, axle_track=104)
```

When I run `robot.drive(speed, angle)` with a higher speed the robot does not accelerate smoothly like when using `robot.straight(distance)` function and almost always is changing slightly the direction when the robot starts.

Have you got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the DriveBase class has any acceleration settings for .drive()
You might be able to create your own function for acceleration on .drive() or you could use a PID controller with a gyro sensor to keep the robot driving in you desired angle/direction.
Hope this helps some!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).